# Walk in the trees, or walk around the trees?

Tags: american-english

Which might be the correct option to go with? I'm utterly confused and I haven't found the right answer anywhere. Please answer it with explanation.

A) I walked in the trees, looking at the sunlight falling through the leaves above me.

B) I walked around the tress, looking at the sunlight falling through the leaves above me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say the second sentence is correct.

The first sentence is with "in", therefore "in" would possibly be misinterpreted to be walking "inside" a tree.

But if I where you. I would prefer to say:

> I walked in the forest, looking at the sunlight falling through the leaves above me.

Or "between":

> I walked between the trees, looking at the sunlight falling through the leaves above me.

Or also with "among":

> I walked among the trees, looking at the sunlight falling through the leaves above me.

Comment: Is among or between more appropriate then around?

Comment: @ApuAhmed Yes, they are.

Comment: If I use among, doesn't it mean that trees are walking with me?

Comment: @ApuAhmed No, "among" means that you're walking and there are a trees surrounding you, which is what you want here.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @ApuAhmed Feel free to mark this if you like and upvote :)

Comment: I am new to this website. I don't know how to mark or upvote :(

Comment: @ApuAhmed Read https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130150/discussion-between-apu-ahmed-and-u12-forward).